# QR Scanning in HoloLens - DLL errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens

I am attempting to implement a QR Code reader from within HoloLens, working off of Mike Taulty's solution (https://mtaulty.com/2016/12/28/windows-10-uwp-qr-code-scanning-with-zxing-and-hololens/). However, I am having an issue with building out the project in Unity, as I am getting a build error: `"Assets\Placeholder.cs(20,9): error CS0103: The name 'MediaFrameQrProcessing' does not exist in the current context"`, which seems to be implying that the DLLs aren't working properly? A already have a DLL by the same name in my project, and I would assume that this DLL would cover this issue, but it appear to not.

I am running Unity 2018.4.1 and Visual Studio 2019. I am building on top of his GitHub repo (https://github.com/mtaulty/QrCodes).

This is the block that throws the build error. `MediaFrameQrProcessing` cannot be found

```
public void OnScan()
    {
        this.textMesh.text = "scanning for 30s";
        #if !UNITY_EDITOR
        MediaFrameQrProcessing.Wrappers.ZXingQrCodeScanner.ScanFirstCameraForQrCode(
            result =>
            {
                UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnAppThread(() =>
            {
                  this.textMesh.text = result ?? "not found";
              },
            false);
            },
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        #endif
    }
```

Expected: Project Builds w/o incident

Actual Results: `Assets\Placeholder.cs(20,9): error CS0103: The name 'MediaFrameQrProcessing' does not exist in the current context` build error. This should be covered by the DLL

Screenshots of the import settings:

[image: Dll Import Settings]

Comment: Did you placed your dll in the `Plugins` folder? Have you configured your DLL to compile for this environment? Can you post a picture of the DLL and its configuration

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I added a picture of the import settings

Comment: Everything seems ok but i don't know what the check mark 'Don't process' means and i don't find it in the documentation... Try un-checking it maybe. I'm pretty sure the issue comes somewhere from this configuration. Maybe look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/PluginInspector.html)

Comment: In Unity 2018.4 the scripting backend is set to IL2CPP by default. If you did not change this to .NET which is marked as obesolete and removed in 2019, the build won't consider your DLL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to try to build with unity2017. I built the unity project in repository with unity2017.4.31f1 and it seemed to  work fine.

Update:

I used 2018.4.3 to create a new project and did some simple tests, this error was not thrown after using such a Import Setting.

[image]